# discord.py How can I clone channels between servers?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a bot that can essentially duplicate a server.
The reason for not using discord.new/templates is because these can only be used for freshly created servers.

To my knowledge, channels and categories don't have the attribute "permissions".. is there a way that I can somehow view all of the permissions of a channel and replicate them for a different channel on a different server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## They are called channel overwrites

to get the overwrites of a channel

```py
overwrites = channel.overwrites  # assuming channel is defined
```

then in the other guild

```py
await guild.create_text_channel(..., overwrites=overwrites)
# the ... is just for example and you can have other arguments there to fit your needs
```

Docs: [TextChannel.overwrites](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.overwrites)